# same navigation drawer in different activities, toolbar error

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to develop an app with multiple activities and the same navigation drawer and toolbar. 
I've created a BaseActivity for initialization of drawer and other activities extend it, but I have problems with toolbar, in particular when using setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

How can I fix this problem?

BaseActivity.java

```
    public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getLayoutResourceId());

}

protected abstract int getLayoutResourceId();

public void initDrawer() {

   drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


   toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            (Activity) this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.food) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, FoodDiary.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FoodDiary.java

```
   public class FoodDiary extends BaseActivity {

        @Override
        protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.content_fooddiary; 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initDrawer();
        ...
        }
```

content_fooddiary.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/left2"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use same Navigation Drawer and Toolbar with different Activities. 
If you want different screens with the same components, you have to use Fragments with one Activity, for example FragmentActivity.

Comment: I implemented the code using the fragments and it actually works. Thanks a lot

Comment: sometimes developer needs more activities.. If in original question every of these two activities already has 3-5 fragments each than approach you proposed will render 1 activity with 6-10 fragments which will be a to complicated to maintain.. :S